# TargetInvocationException in VS 2013 Ultimate xUnit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, xunit.net

After install VS 2013 Ultimate not work xunit tests in VS 2012 and VS 2013. I have exception in debug: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". Inner exeption: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation". How decided this problem?

Comment: There will be an inner exception, which will be the original exception - the `TargetInvocationException` is basically a wrapper due to the use of reflection. Look at the inner exception and you should be able to get more of an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in version 0.99.0 of the runner.

You can see more details [here](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9895).

Uninstalling the 0.99.0 runner VSIX and installing the [0.95.4 runner](https://xunit.codeplex.com/releases/view/114414) should solve your issue.

Comment: I have just installed  0.95.4 runner, tests work in VS 2012, but not work in VS 2013. This will be fixed in 0.99.1. http://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/470067

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with v 0.99.6. Possible a different cause, but same symptom? I filed a bug report  https://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9926

Comment: I'm using version 0.99.8 and I have the same problem

Comment: @Moy, I'd log and issue on the GitHub pages, or try tweeting them, I've had a help with a missing feature this way.